# Show that the Gamma integral exists for $x > 0$.

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

We need to show that the Gamma Integral exists for $\int_0^\infty u^{x−1}e^{−u}\mathop{du}$ before solving more proofs in a question in my calc textbook. I have done everything except this.

I don't know how to show this. Using $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n u^{x−1}e^{−u}\mathop{du}$ I tried integrating by parts but we end up with $\int_0^n e^{−u}$ which is not integrable.

Comment: Are you sure that $\int_0^n e^{-u}\mathop{du}$ is not integrable?

Answer (score 3):

You are integrating a function that is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. You just have to check the integrability at the endpoint of the interval.

- At $0$ you have $u^{x-1}e^{-u} \underset{u \rightarrow 0+}{\sim} u^{x-1}$ which is a known integral. It converges if and only if $1-x < 1$.
- At $+ \infty$ you don't have an equivalent that would be that simple but still the exponential dominates everything. More rigourously, you know that
  $$
  u^2 u^{x-1}e^{-u} = u^{x+1}e^{-u} \underset{u \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
  $$
  so there exists $A > 0$ such that forall $u > A$, $u^{x-1}e^{-u} \leq \frac{A}{u^2}$. The right hand side is integrable at $+\infty$ and everything is non negative so your integral converges at $+\infty$.